# HTMl alignment issue

Tags: asp.net, html

I am working asp.net 3.5. My page is displaying properly in IE but not in mozilla. See The image. Can anyone help how to solve this issue.  I am hiding or showing Reject/ Reschedule : option on click event.

[image]

```
<tr>
    <td align="right" style="padding-top: 4px" id="trRejResch" runat="server">
        Reject/ Reschedule :
    </td>
    <td align="left" style="height: 25px;" id="trRejResch1" runat="server">
        <telerik:RadComboBox OnClientKeyPressing="onKeyPressing" ID="txtRejResch" MarkFirstMatch="true"
            runat="server" Width="157px" Height="60px" CollapseDelay="0" CollapseAnimation-Duration="0"
            DataSourceID="sqlDSRejResch" DropDownWidth="154px" AllowCustomText="true" DataTextField="nTypeDesc">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDSRejResch" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="select nTypeDesc from NoteType where nType in (2,3)" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab firebug for Firefox and use it's layout tab to determine whats going on.

The div you are defining to hold the reject/schedule drop down just isn't large enough and it's overflowing and spilling down.

Also, make sure you are using the HTML 4.01 Strict doctype if you can.  This will help make sure that the different browsers display the same thing.